# Running gcloud command in php not working

Tags: php, shell, google-cloud-platform, scripting, gcloud

I am trying to run shell commands from PHP using

```
 <?PHP

 $output = shell_exec('gcloud --version'." 2>&1");
 echo "$output";

 ?>
```

The output which I get is

```
sh: 1: gcloud: not found
```

When I try to do

```
 shell_exec('ls -l')
```

It works as expected. I have related posts on StackOverflow to use Rest API instead on this. But I have created a big script with gcloud commands. I am running my shell scripts in Terminal in mac. Can anyone help me understand the issue. May be required to install sdk, tried that still got same issue.

Comment: The Cloud SDK CLI is a Python script and is not a binary executable. You need to launch a shell (sh/bash/csh/etc) with `gcloud` as an argument. Use the full path. Use this command to find out where it is installed on your system `which -a gcloud`.

Comment: Can you please give some example command? I have less idea in bash scripting

Comment: No, you do not need any shell to run python scripts

Comment: Where are you running your code? On which product?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I am running my code in PHP in mac and using Xampp server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read up on `Relative Path` vs `Absolute Path` of a file/dir.

When you code `shell_exec('gcloud --version'...`, you are using `relative path`.
One way to resolve your issue is to specify the `absolute path` to `gcloud` command which can be determined from `bash` command line by typing:
`which gcloud` and you might get a result like
`/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud`

Then, change your PHP code to `shell_exec('/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud --version'...`

Comment: still same error..i tried which gcloud command then used that path here..shell_exec('/Users/shivani/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud --version'." 2>&1");